# Extend/expand data frame with column of lists each into a row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a a data frame of the following type:

```
df <- data.frame("col1" = c(1,2,3,4))
df$col2 <- list(list(1,1,1),list(2,2,2),list(3,3,3),list(4,4,4))
df$col3 <- list(c(1,1,1),c(2,2,2),c(3,3,3),c(4,4,4))

df
```

And get:

```
 col1    col2    col3
1    1 1, 1, 1 1, 1, 1
2    2 2, 2, 2 2, 2, 2
3    3 3, 3, 3 3, 3, 3
4    4 4, 4, 4 4, 4, 4
```

Now I would like to manipulate this data frame to get something like:

```
 col1    col3
1    1    1
     1    1
     1    1 
2    2    2
     2    2
     2    2 
3    3    3
     3    3
     3    3
...
```

Now I can do this with a simple loop. For each row I convert the list into a data frame. I then use `rbind` to append the data frames into a single one.

My question is: how do I do this with vectorized function?

I have tried `apply`, `sapply`, `mapply` and `Reduce`but with no success. `apply`was the only that actually execute but produced incorrect results (got only the first element of each list).

Comment: We can try `lst <- lapply(df[-1], unlist)` and then use `data.frame(lst)`

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding creating a data.frame with list columns to begin with.

Comment: @akrun You suggestion seems to work. Want to add that as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks.

Comment: @user2051561  Thank you.  Posted as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the first column (`df[-1]`), loop over the other columns, `unlist` and then convert the `list` to `data.frame`

```
lst <- lapply(df[-1], unlist)
dfN <- data.frame(lst)
```